# What is the purpose of setting a variable default to empty in bash?

Tags: bash, default-value

In general, this syntax is used to guarantee a value, potentially a default argument.

> (from the Bash reference manual)
>
> ${parameter:-word}
>
> If parameter is unset **or null**, the expansion of word is substituted. 
>       Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

What would be the purpose of defaulting a variable to empty if the substitution is only chosen when the variable is empty anyway?

For reference, I'm looking at /lib/lsb/init-functions.

Comment: What syntax are you talking about?

Comment: When parameter is empty then word might not be empty and is used. When parameter is not null, substitution is meaningful.

Comment: FYI, a `bash` check of `[ -z "${VAR}" ]` is different than `[ -z ${VAR} ]` when undefined vs. null.

Comment: @Barmar `newname="${oldname:-}"` -- I didn't know about `set -u`, so I interpreted this line to mean "set newname to oldname's value or nothing if oldname is unset/null", which would be equivalent to `oldname="$newname"`.

Comment: The syntax you're asking about should be in the question, not a comment.

Comment: users/7422249/fred edited it in, I missed it while copying.

http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41915810/revisions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Null" means the variable has a value, and this value is an empty string.  The shell knows the variable exists.

"Unset" means the variable has not been defined : it does not exist as far as the shell is concerned.

In its usual mode, the shell will expand null and unset variable to an empty string.  But there is a mode (`set -u`) that allows the shell to throw a runtime error if a variable is expanded when it is unset.  It is good practice to enable this mode, because it is very easy to simply mis-type a variable name and get difficult to debug errors.

It can actually be useful from a computing perspective to differentiate between unset and empty variables, you can assign separate semantics to each case.  For instance, say you have a function that may receive an argument.  You may want to use a (non-null) default value if the parameter is unset, or any value passed to the function (including an empty string) if the parameter is set.  You would do something like :

```
my_function()
{
  echo "${1-DEFAULT_VALUE}"
}
```

Then, the two commands below would provide different outputs:

```
my_function     # Echoes DEFAULT_VALUE
my_function ""  # Echoes an empty line
```

There is also a type of expansion that does not differentiate between null and not set :

```
"${VAR:-DEFAULT_VALUE}"
```

They are both useful depending on what you need.

The way to test if a variable is set or not (without running the risk of a runtime error) is the following type of expansion :

```
"${VAR+VALUE}"
```

This will expand to an empty string if `VAR` is unset, or to VALUE if it is set (empty or with a value).  Very useful when you need it.

Generally, it is helpful to:

- Declare variables explicitely
- `set -u` to prevent silent expansion failure
- Explicitly handle unset variables through the appropriate expansion

This will make your scripts more reliable, and easier to debug.

Comment: As an aside, `"${VAR-}"` and `"${VAR:-}"` always yield the same result, but in this specific case, this is what their specification dictates when the default value supplied is an empty string.

Comment: "There is also a type of expansion that does not differentiate between null and not set : ${VAR:-DEFAULT_VALUE}"

This is the version I saw in `init-functions`, but with `DEFAULT_VALUE=""` -- to be clear, you're saying that `set -u` or not, there is no difference in the captured value? Does that mean the author meant to write `${VAR-}`, or is there another reason for it?

Example: (93) `if $(kill -0 "${pid:-}" 2>/dev/null 2>&1); then ... fi`

Comment: `${VAR:-}` and `${VAR:-""}` are the same thing (consecutive double quotes denote an empty string).  When `set -u` is activated, it is necessary to use an expansion that tolerates unset variable, else the script will fail, but it otherwise does not modify the result of any successful expansion.  I use the `${VAR-}` because it is shorter and I am used to it, but someone else might be used to the other one, and with an empty string they are equivalent, so no real advantage one way or the other except for one less character...

Comment: So in my example, the expansion might be `kill -0 "" 2>/dev/null 2>&1` (from `"${pid-}"`), which is syntactically valid but silently fails, while `kill -0 2>/dev/null 2>&1` (from `${pid-}`) is syntactically invalid and causes the script to fail because of the missing argument. Is that more or less correct? Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is the other way around : `${pid-}` wil result in `kill -0`, while `"${pid-}"` wil result in `kill -0 ""`.  The redirection makes little sense to me : `2>/dev/null 2>&1` redirects stderr twice.  `1>/dev/null 2>&1` would make more sense in terms of getting rid of any output, unless there is something I am missing.

Comment: Yeah, that looked wrong when I wrote it, I accidentally switched lines (93 to 96).